# Will only the last or-operator work with the and-operator?

Tags: c#, operators

(Sorry, this is very hard to explain for me)

So even if the ped is aiming, it also checks if the ped exists? or only when the ped's weapon is ready to shoot? (since it's right next to the and operator.)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40lI7.png)

Comment: Please copy your code into the question as text.

Answer (score 1):

See this little fiddle:

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool result1 = true || false && false;
    bool result2 = (true || false) && false;
    Console.WriteLine(result1); // Outputs: true
    Console.WriteLine(result2); // Outputs: false
}
```

So braces do matter here. In the first case true is returned even though the final condition is false. That final condition is not evaluated.
In the second case the final condition is evaluated and is crucial for the result.

See more info on c# operators and precedence here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-